continuous functional calculus on C$^*$-algebra
Let $(A,\gamma)$ be a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded C$^*$-algebra. For an element $x\in A$ with $x=x^{-1}$, I have already shown that $|x|=u|x|^{-1}u^*$ by uniqueness of the polar decomposition. In the next step I need to show that $|x|^t=u|x|^{-t}u^*$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.
By continuous functional calculus, we can consider $|x|^{\pm t}$ since the functions $x^t$ and $x^{-t}$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. My idea was using $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t(t-1)...(t-n+1)}{n!}(x-1)^n$ to show that $f_n(u|x|^{-1}u^*)=u\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{t(t-1)...(t-n+1)}{n!}(|x|-1)^n\right)u^*$ holds and then concluding that the same relation holds for $x^t=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. I think that I need $|x|\in B_1(1)$ since the radius of convergence is 1, right?
Thanks for your help.

You don’t have to choose those specific functions. By Stone-Weierstrass, given any closed interval $[a, b]$ where $0 < a < b$, you always have a sequence of polynomials $f_n(x)$ which converges to $x^t$ uniformly on $[a, b]$. In particular, given any positive invertible $T$, if you choose $[a, b]$ large enough so that it contains the spectrum of $T$, then $f_n(T) \to T^t$. It is easy to check that applying polynomials to an operator commutes with conjugating by a unitary, i.e., $f_n(uTu^\ast) = uf_n(T)u^\ast$. By taking limits, this yields $(uTu^\ast)^t = uT^tu^\ast$. Applying this to $T = |x|^{-1}$ gives what you want.
The moral here is that continuous functional calculus always commutes with conjugating by a unitary - in fact, more generally, continuous functional calculus always commutes with applying $\ast$-homomorphisms.

Thank you David .
